# dyld: Library not loaded...GLKit framework not loaded?

Tags: xcode4.2

When I am trying to include GLKit Library in my Xcode project using Xcode 4.2 on iOS 5, I am getting this error

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/74FBF264-3F42-4320-9CBC-A86C1D470649/Demo.app/Demo
Reason: image not found

Please help me, I am struggling with this problem from many days though I have tried many internet solutions

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that any hardware you run it has iOS version 5 or higher installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build folder, then do a build again.